# What does a quote mean in front of a vector in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Suppose you have the following line of code in clojure. What do you need the quote for?

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])
```

Comment: https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_quote; https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#quote

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quote prevents evaluation.  By default, all expressions are evaluated in Clojure.  Using a quote in front of the expression prevents the evaluation.  <s>Most expressions in Clojure are self-evaluating (they evaluate to themselves).  The two main exceptions are symbols and lists.</s> **Edit:** See comment from @amalloy below and response.

In this case, the quote is creating a literal vector whose first element is the symbol `clojure.string`, the second element is the keyword `:as` and the third is the symbol `str`.

Without the quote, `(require [clojure.string :as str])`, would try to evaluate the symbols `clojure.string` and `str` and the value would be whatever the var bound to those symbols contains (or an error, if there is nothing bound).

Here is an example demonstrating the difference.  Let's say you have the following two `def`s.

```clj
(def a 16)
(def b 12)
```

Now, `'[a 14 b]` would evaluate to the vector `[a 14 b]`.  But, `[a 14 b]` would evaluate to `[16 14 12]`.

See the [Evaluation](https://clojure.org/reference/evaluation) section on `clojure.org` for the details on exactly how a symbol is resolved in Clojure.

You might also find the documentation for [quote](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/quote) to be helpful, as also the section on Clojure [syntax](https://clojure.org/guides/learn/syntax).

Comment: Nit: I don't think it's useful to say that most expressions evaluate to themselves. In fact very little evaluates to itself: mostly just keywords and numbers. Most relevantly, a vector doesn't evaluate to itself: if it did, you wouldn't need a quote in this answer! Instead, evaluating a vector entails evaluating its elements and placing them in a vector.

Comment: You are correct.  I struggled with what phrase to use instead of "expressions".  Perhaps "primitive elements" would have been better.  Or maybe I should remove the sentence altogether.